# Expanding listView from bottom

Tags: html, css, windows-8, winjs

I'm trying to figure a way to expand a Windows 8 listView from the bottom. Essentially, I have a listView populated with a few items. I want these items to begin at the bottom of the listView container. When I add to the list, I want them to shift upwards. Once the listView containers reaches/fills a desired height, I'd like the listView scroll bar to become usable.

As it stands now, I can position a listView at the bottom of my screen and make it a height that only contains my items. But when I add items, it simply remains the same height and adds the scroll bar. If I make a listView my desired final height with only a few items not filling the entire height, then my items start at the top.

Any ideas if this is even possible?

Comment: So I know the height of the listView is absolute and will not adjust automatically. I'd like a CSS solution, but a JS approach may be the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listview` only support [GridLayout and ListLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211833.aspx) which layout the content inside list view using `position: absolute` (seen using DOM explorer in debugger). It is less likely that css or js can come for help to customize the listview layout for your requirement to layout bottom to top. One can try to see if a custom layout manager be built for listview. but afaik - it is not documented.

You will likely need to build at [custom winjs control](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/10/11/building-a-custom-control-using-the-windows-library-for-javascript-winjs.aspx). The custom control can use `-ms-flexbox` display style (css3 flex layout) which allows to pack the content in a div towards end. The custom control need to bind to dataSource, and render items using the given item template.

Example: you can see that page content elements are packed towards the end of the page.
html:

```
<div class="flexlayout fragment">
    <header role="banner">
        <button class="win-backbutton" disabled type="button"></button>
        <h1 class="titlearea win-type-ellipsis">
            <span class="pagetitle">flexlayout page</span>
        </h1>
    </header>
    <section role="main">
        <div class="content">
            <h3>page content goes here.</h3>
            <h3>page content goes here.</h3>
            <h3>page content goes here.</h3>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

css:

```
.flexlayout.fragment .content
{
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-pack: end;

}

.fragment {
    display: -ms-grid;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of placing a listView at the bottom of the screen that would only hold a single item. Then, each time I added a new item, increasing the height of the listView (via JavaScript) until it reached the height of the screen, in which case I would let the scroll bar activate. Would that work?

Comment: Well I completely did away with the listView. It was too much hassle for what it was worth. But I accepted your answer because if I had stayed with the listView I would have utilized your approach.